# Problems with SWReveal ( Slide menu)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a problem with the following code:

```
class VCParticipanteMenu: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource 
{

    var menuNameArr:Array = [String]()
    var iconeImage:Array = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        menuNameArr = ["Inicio","Actividades","Información","Mapa","Comunicación","Perfil","FeedBack!","Cerrar Sesión"]
        iconeImage = [UIImage(named: "Inicio")!,UIImage(named: "eventos")!,UIImage(named: "informacion")!,UIImage(named: "mapa")!,UIImage(named: "comunicacion")!,UIImage(named: "perfil")!,UIImage(named: "feedback")!,UIImage(named: "cerrarSesion")!]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuNameArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TVCParticipanteMenu") as! TVCParticipanteMenu

        cell.imgIcon.image = iconeImage[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblView.text = menuNameArr[indexPath.row]
        print(cell.lblView.text!)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let revealViewController:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()

        let cell:TVCParticipanteMenu = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TVCParticipanteMenu
        print(cell.lblView.text!)

        if cell.lblView.text! == "Inicio"
        {
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let desController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCParticipante") as! VCParticipante
            let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)

            revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
        }
        if cell.lblView.text! == "Actividades"
        {
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let desController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCParticipanteAct") as! VCParticipanteAct
            let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)

            revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

All good but at the moment of selecting "Inicio" or "Actividades" nothing appears, after selecting another option I appear the above and so on

this is  the code of the other viewControllers

```
import UIKit

class VCParticipante: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
```

and

```
import UIKit

class VCParticipanteAct: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

All this after a login ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

didDeselectRowAt to didselectRowAt